# Flowplayer - get # of seconds

Tags: flowplayer

Is it possible to get the number of seconds of the playing video in flowplayer?

Regards.

Answer (score 6):

```
flowplayer('myPlayer').getTime();
```

[Player Methods](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/api/player.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$f().getClip().fullDuration
```

...